# Accepting and encoding list of Encodable

Tags: swift

I'm writing a function for calling into JavaScript from Swift and would like to accept the name of a function and a list of arguments to call with. The list should be able to contain anything that I can convert into JSON.

e.g.

```
callJS(function: "console.log", withArgs: [1, "Hello"])
```

My naive attempt at this was this:

```
func callJS(function: String, withArgs args: [Encodable]) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try! encoder.encode(list)
    let jsonArgs = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

    executeJS("\(function)(...\(jsonArgs))")
}
```

Unfortunately, that fails at runtime with the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Array does not conform to Encodable because Encodable does not conform to itself. You must use a concrete type to encode or decode.

Is there any way to get the compiler to embed the types from the call sites, so that `Encodable` knows what to encode?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use tuple types instead of an `Array`. The drawback of this is that the arity of the function needs to be hardcoded.

```
func callJS(function: String) {
    executeJS("\(function)()")
}

func callJS<A: Encodable>(function: String, withArg arg: A) {
    let a = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([arg]), encoding: .utf8)!
    executeJS("\(function)(\(a))")
}

func callJS<A: Encodable, B: Encodable>(function: String, withArgs args: (A, B)) {
    let a = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.0]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let b = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.1]), encoding: .utf8)!
    executeJS("\(function)(\(a),\(b))")
}

func callJS<A: Encodable, B: Encodable, C: Encodable>(function: String, withArgs args: (A, B, C)) {
    let a = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.0]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let b = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.1]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let c = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.2]), encoding: .utf8)!
    executeJS("\(function)(\(a),\(b),\(c))")
}

func callJS<A: Encodable, B: Encodable, C: Encodable, D: Encodable>(function: String, withArgs args: (A, B, C, D)) {
    let a = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.0]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let b = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.1]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let c = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.2]), encoding: .utf8)!
    let d = try! String(data: self.encoder.encode([args.3]), encoding: .utf8)!
    executeJS("\(function)(\(a),\(b),\(c),\(d))")
}

// and so on for each arity that you need to support
```

This could then be called in a straightforward matter:

```
callJS(function: "console.log", withArgs: (1, "Hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I believe is caused because the complier is being sent confusing information, you are trying to pass both a `String` and `Int` so it throws a wobbler and doesn't know what to do with life.

Which does work when used like so:

```
var array: Array<Codable> = [1, 2, "Hello"]
```

But not when used in the function, so lets say if all the objects to be in said array were of the same type you could simply change the function to:

```
func callJS<Value: Encodable>(function: String, withArgs args: [Value])
```

However if you wish to use multiple object in your array you may wish to look at this piece of code I once wrote ([Found here](https://gist.github.com/harrytwright/6cadb8e19c12525a7bf2b844baaeaa8a)) where I realised there are limitations with `Array` and `Codable` so built this `AnyCodable` to be used where you would use `Array<Any>` or `Array<Codable>`.

To be used like so:

```
func callJS(function: String, withArgs args: [AnyCodable]) {
     let encoder = JSONEncoder()
     let data = try! encoder.encode(list)
     let jsonArgs = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

     executeJS("\(function)(...\(jsonArgs))")
}

callJS(function: "console.log", withArgs: [1, "Hello"])
```

Note: Limitations are that the it only works with stdlib structures at this state

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how it works? I was also thinking that maybe it would be possible to store the dynamic type (`type(of: _)`) of the value with the value somehow. I still don't understand exactly why this line works: `try (self._box._base as! Codable).encode(to: encoder)`

Comment: Oh, and also, for me it's, unfortunately, a requirement that it works with any `Codeable` and not just primitive types.

Comment: I works exactly like `AnyHashable`, so the `_ConcreteCodableBox` holds the `Codable` value and is type safe as only a `Codable` value can be initialised inside. So when we call the encode method, even though according to `_AnyCodableBox` said `_base` property is of `Any` it can only be a `Codable` value so we just call its encode method like `JSONEncoder` would do?

Comment: Also getting it to work with AnyCodable value the user would create was the next step, never got around to figuring it out, however, I have an idea and will attempt to see if I can get it get it to work

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck After running the code inside a playground, the `AnyCodable` struct will allow you to encode any custom struct/class. However, decoding the custom struct cannot be done with `AnyCodable` (It decides to place the values inside a dictionary instead)